# Use of plot command with a foreach loop variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Edit: I wrote some nonsense before. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

I'm trying to repeat a plot in a foreach loop with the domain of the plot shifting in each iteration. I've tried shifting the parameters in the 'domain' argument to 'plot', i.e. domain={\i:2.2*pi+\i}. This fails to compile. It doesn't seem to like the \i variable in the domain. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {10, 20, 30}
  \draw[] plot[samples=100,domain={\i:2.2*pi + \i}] function {sin(x)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I don't want a plot with axes, and I need the plot to be in the same units as the rest of my tikz drawing. So, I may be wrong, but I don't think 'addplot' is a valid solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `foreach` with `\foreach`.

`plot function{<gnuplot formula>}` is used for `gnuplot`, see `pgfmanual sec 22.6 Plotting a Function Using Gnuplot`.

If you want to draw the function plot with pure tikz, follow the examples in `pgfmanual sec 22.5 Plotting a Function`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {10, 20, 30}
  \draw plot[samples=100,domain={\i:(2.2*pi + \i)}] (\x, {sin(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: foreach was just a typo in this post. It's great that I can do it without gnuplot. Thanks.